# Obter valores com jquery query builder e selectize

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

Estou tentando resolver um problema há um tempo, mas não consegui ainda.

Este código está usando Jquery Query Builder e o plug-in select, para permitir a seleção de vários valores.

Está tudo bem, exceto que não consegui obter os valores selecionados no input. A tela abaixo mostra como está a interface gráfica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código js segue abaixo:

```
$(document).ready(() => {

    let builder = $('#builder');

    const optionsValue = {
        request_type: [
            { value: 'request1', label: 'Request 1' },
            { value: 'request2', label: 'Request 2' },
            { value: 'request3', label: 'Request 3' }
        ],
        priority: [
            { value: 'alta', label: 'Alta' },
            { value: 'media', label: 'Média' },
            { value: 'baixa', label: 'Baixa' }
        ],
        locality: [
            { value: 'rj', label: 'Rio de Janeiro' },
            { value: 'cr', label: 'Curitiba' },
            { value: 'po', label: 'Porto Alegre' }
        ]
    };

    // Montar opções para o query builder
    const buildOptions = (result) => {

        let options = {};
        let filters = [];

        for (let key in result) {

            let values = result[key];

            for (let key_value in values) {
                let value = values[key_value];
                value.optgroup = key;

                value.field = values[key_value].id;
                let identifier_value = values[key_value].id;
                let options_value = optionsValue[identifier_value];

                value.valueSetter = function(rule, val) {
                    rule.$el.find('.rule-value-container input')[0].selectize.setValue(eval("[" + val + "]"));
                }

                value.valueGetter = function(rule) {
                    return rule.$el.find('.rule-value-container input')[0].selectize.getValue().split(',');
                }

                value.plugin_config = {
                    valueField: 'value',
                    labelField: 'label',
                    searchField: 'label',
                    sortField: 'label',
                    plugins: ['remove_button']
                };

                filters.push(value);
            }
        }

        let lang = {
            operators: {
              equal: 'Igual a',
              not_equal: 'Diferente de',
              contains: 'Contém',
              not_contains: 'Não contém',
              greater: 'Maior que',
              less: 'Menor que',
              is_null: 'É nulo'
            }
        }

        options.allow_empty = { allow_empty: true };
        options.filters = filters;
        options.lang = lang;

        return options;
    }

    // Obter os dados
    const getData = () => {
        return fetch('./request/getdata.php')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(data => {

            let result = JSON.parse(data);

            let options = buildOptions(result);

            builder.queryBuilder(options);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Ocorreu um erro:', error);
        });
    }

    // Inicializar os campos com os valores
    const clickSelect = () => {
        $(document).on('change', '.rules-list li .rule-filter-container select', function() {
            let parent = $(this).closest(".rule-container");
            let input_text = parent.find(".rule-value-container input");

            let selectedValue = $(this).val();

            input_text.selectize({
                plugins: ["restore_on_backspace", "clear_button", "remove_button"],
                delimiter: " - ",
                persist: true,
                maxItems: null,
                valueField: "value",
                labelField: "label",
                searchField: ["label", "value"],
                options: optionsValue[selectedValue],
                allowEmptyOption: true,
                multiple: true,
                input: 'selectize'
            });
        });

    }

    // Obter os dados do query builder
    const getQueryBuilderData = () => {
        $("#qbinfo").on("click", function(){

            var rules = builder.queryBuilder('getRules');

            console.log(rules);
        });
    }

    getData().then(() => {
        clickSelect();
        getQueryBuilderData();
    });

});
```

Quando o método **getQueryBuilderData()** é executado, tenho o resultado abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que o índice value retorna com um array, e não com os valores que eu selecionei.

Não tenho certeza, mas acredito que o problema possa estar em um desses dois métodos:

```
value.valueSetter = function(rule, val) {
    rule.$el.find('.rule-value-container input')[0].selectize.setValue(eval("[" + val + "]"));
}

value.valueGetter = function(rule) {
    return rule.$el.find('.rule-value-container input')[0].selectize.getValue().split(',');
}
```

Quando faço debug, método getValue sempre retorna vazio.